# Flutter SVG shows just one color

Tags: flutter, svg, dart

I want to add `SVG` file in my project, and I used flutter_svg: ^0.17.3,
my project shows the `SVG` but in fact, my `SVG` file has 2 colors but in the project, it shows just in one color!

and source of svg file:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
    <defs>
        <style>.fa-secondary{opacity:.4}</style>
    </defs>
    <path d="M208 80a128 128 0 1 1-90.51 37.49A127.15 127.15 0 0 1 208 80m0-80C93.12 0 0 93.12 0 208s93.12 208 208 208 208-93.12 208-208S322.88 0 208 0z" class="fa-secondary"/><path d="M504.9 476.7L476.6 505a23.9 23.9 0 0 1-33.9 0L343 405.3a24 24 0 0 1-7-17V372l36-36h16.3a24 24 0 0 1 17 7l99.7 99.7a24.11 24.11 0 0 1-.1 34z" class="fa-primary"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

The SVGs created by some graphical tools, add clutter and other markup not understood by `flutter_svg` which might create problems.

Use [SVG Cleaner](https://github.com/RazrFalcon/svgcleaner) on the images first.
Added benefit the output images will be smaller in size.

Comment: Thumbs up for the recommendation, never knew this thing existed, but that did not solve the problem unfortunately.

Comment: @om-ha Thanks. Does the SVG work fine in a web-browser? Also was the result for SVG Cleaner success?

Comment: `SVG Cleaner` is an amazing tool to come across, but it did not solve `flutter_svg` core issue. Which was lack fo support for `filter` element in SVG. Whatever you do and clean in the SVG file, you cannot get rid of that `filter` element without re-designing it or re-manipulating it from the illustration/design program. Here are the sources for `flutter_svg` lack of support for `filter` element: [here](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/53) and [here].(https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/442).

Comment: Other solutions would be to use it in a `WebView`, but as the author said it's not idea to use a `WebView` for each icon in your app! WebView approach is suitable only for large/full-screen SVG's, not small repetitive SVG's. [Source](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/166#issuecomment-784746493)

Comment: As for `flutter_svg` support for elements like `filter`/`effects` is related with flutter engine. The changes are there in flutter engine upstream but I suppose it's highly challenging to implement them in `flutter_svg` or some other reason related to author priorities. See [this](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/231#issuecomment-541838585) and this excerpt from `TODO` section `Filters/effects (will require upstream engine changes, but doable).` [here](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg#todo).

Comment: Turned my comments into an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69604101/10830091).

Answer (score 4):

This answer covers `filter`/`effects`/`blur` in `flutter_svg` AKA the most probable reason why your SVG is being rendered incorrectly/shows missing colors.

This answer was adapted and extrapolated from my [comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61092994/flutter-svg-shows-just-one-color/65033951?noredirect=1#comment123026111_65033951).

### What's not supported?

- `filter` svg element
- And effects/blur elements.

### Reason for lack of support

Filters/effects will require upstream flutter engine changes as stated by [the package author](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg#todo). Apparently those changes [could be ready](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/231#issuecomment-541838585), but for unknown reasons `filter` support is not there yet. Perhaps there exists only highly complex, suboptimal low-performance implementations [are possible so far](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/478#issuecomment-766952953).

### Source for lack of support

- Primary issue for tracking this: [#53](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/53).
- Repo's TODO section: [source](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg#todo).
- Some explanation on background work required for proper support: [source](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/231#issuecomment-541838585).
- Example error message for unsupported files: [source](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/442).

### Workaround -- WebView

Disclaimer: You can render an SVG inside WebView (e.g. `webview_flutter` package) but as the author said it's not ideal to use a WebView for each icon in your app! WebView approach is suitable only for large/full-screen SVG's that may have some animations or special SVG elements that are unsupported. This is not a viable option for small repetitive SVG's.

See `flutter_svg` author's [recommendation here](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/166#issuecomment-784746493).

### Test your svg file for support

1. Add `flutter_svg` package

```
dependencies:
  flutter_svg: ^0.23.0+1
```

2. Parse your SVG file using `SvgParser` for debugging purposes:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/parser.dart';

class SvgTest extends StatelessWidget {
  SvgTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  // widget prop
  final String assetName = "assets/images/sample_svg.svg";
  bool fireOnce = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // widget build
    if (!fireOnce) {
      fireOnce = true;
      parseSVG(assetName);
    }
    return Container();
  }

  // widget method
  Future<void> parseSVG(String assetName) async {
    final SvgParser parser = SvgParser();
    final svgString = await rootBundle.loadString(assetName);
    try {
      await parser.parse(svgString, warningsAsErrors: true);
      print('SVG is supported');
    } catch (e) {
      print('SVG contains unsupported features');
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

3. Observe the results in console/output.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this SVG bellow or try again with 0.17.4:

```
<svg width="512" height="512" viewBox="0 0 512 512" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g clip-path="url(#clip0)">
<path opacity="0.4" d="M208 80C237.613 80.0002 266.311 90.2684 289.202 109.055C312.094 127.842 327.763 153.985 333.54 183.029C339.317 212.074 334.845 242.223 320.885 268.339C306.925 294.456 284.342 314.924 256.982 326.257C229.623 337.589 199.181 339.085 170.842 330.488C142.504 321.892 118.023 303.735 101.571 279.113C85.1187 254.49 77.713 224.924 80.6157 195.453C83.5185 165.982 96.55 138.43 117.49 117.49C129.348 105.566 143.453 96.1132 158.989 89.678C174.526 83.2428 191.184 79.9533 208 80V80ZM208 0C93.12 0 0 93.12 0 208C0 322.88 93.12 416 208 416C322.88 416 416 322.88 416 208C416 93.12 322.88 0 208 0Z" fill="#999999"/>
<path d="M504.9 476.7L476.6 505C474.379 507.234 471.738 509.008 468.829 510.218C465.92 511.428 462.801 512.05 459.65 512.05C456.499 512.05 453.38 511.428 450.471 510.218C447.562 509.008 444.921 507.234 442.7 505L343 405.3C340.773 403.065 339.009 400.414 337.808 397.497C336.607 394.58 335.992 391.455 336 388.3V372L372 336H388.3C391.455 335.992 394.58 336.607 397.497 337.808C400.414 339.009 403.065 340.773 405.3 343L505 442.7C509.479 447.231 511.982 453.35 511.964 459.721C511.945 466.091 509.405 472.196 504.9 476.7V476.7Z" fill="black"/>
</g>
<defs>
<clipPath id="clip0">
<rect width="512" height="512" fill="white"/>
</clipPath>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I try my svg with 0.17.4 but still not work; with your svg it works :) but a little diffrenet in style!!